# Why can't header in framework be found?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm using a framework but getting an error trying to #include the header from the framework, but can't see anything that's configured incorrectly.

I #include the framework within the .m file as:

```
#import <NameOfFramework/NameOFHeaderInFramework.h>
```

But get the error:

> "NameOfFramework/NameOFHeaderInFramework.h file not found"

The framework has been added as an embedded binary and the framework search path is set to $(PROJECT_DIR) which is where the framework is located (if I remove the #include line, the project compiles and builds, indicating that framework is being found during the build phase)

Screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI8HX.png)

Comment: You did the framework search paths. What about the _header_ search paths?

Comment: @matt Thats set to $(PROJECT_DIR) also.